# UPDMAP file missing? Trying to install cm-super on MikTeX

Tags: packages, miktex

I am going through the painful process of trying to install `cm-super`. I'm following the instructions on the install file.

Here is the one I am stuck on:

```
4.1) [not for VTeX/Free] Instruct dvips and pdftex to use these fonts:

   a) [on teTeX, but not on TeX Live]
      edit the file .../texmf/dvips/config/updmap
      and add the following lines into the extra_modules section:

../cm-super/cm-super-t1.map
../cm-super/cm-super-ts1.map
../cm-super/cm-super-t2a.map
../cm-super/cm-super-t2b.map
../cm-super/cm-super-t2c.map
../cm-super/cm-super-x2.map

   b) run the updmap script.
```

When I go to the directory `C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\dvips\config`, I see nothing resembling an updmap file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not install it manually. Use the miktex console.